# Unzip files on Cordova 4.0 - APP Builder Telerik plataform - Plugins not working

Tags: android, cordova, telerik, cordova-plugins, telerik-appbuilder

How to Unzip files on Cordova 4.0 on APP Builder Telerik plataform...

I've tried 4 plugins, all of then are undefined when I call them on code...

Does anyone know a plugin that works on telerik plataform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely to do with how you are installing the plugins. A few things I would check:

1) Try one or more plugins from the [Verified Plugins Marketplace](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova) (click the "Try in Telerik Platform" button to clone a demo app).

2) [Check the docs](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/using-plugins/using-custom-plugins/add-custom-plugins) to make sure you are installing your custom plugins correctly.

3) If all else fails, [submit a support ticket](https://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/my-support-tickets)!